# na.rm function not working when running summary statistics

Tags: r

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrdXG.png)I am a novice in R and I am having trouble running simple t-tests when my dataset contains N/A values. I have recoded "N/A" to "NA" in my dataset, but for some reason, the "na.rm" function does not work. My script is as follows:

Any suggestions on how to get the "na.rm" function to work with N/A values in R? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can‘t use `mean` as you do in your pipe.

Either use `mean(Book1$MAP_MCS, na.rm = TRUE)`

Or use dplyr‘s summarize:

```
library(dplyr)
Book1 %>%
  summarize(mean_MAP_MCS = mean(MAP_MCS, na.rm = TRUE))
```